# Missing text from <memo> field in table in report

Tags: ms-access, enterprise-architect

I have multiple models in Sparx Enterprise Architect in file-based, i.e. using MS Access.

I'm using a custom template to populate a table with data from object's properties, including some with `<memo>` fields.

This is the query I'm using in the template fragment:

```
SELECT 
    obj.object_id,
    obj.Stereotype,
    objp.Property as Prop,
    switch(objp.Value = '<memo>', objp.Notes, objp.Value LIKE '{*}', 
           NULL, 1=1, objp.Value) AS Val,
    (SELECT tobj2.ea_guid & tobj2.Name 
     FROM t_object tobj2 
     WHERE tobj2.ea_guid = objp.Value) AS [Obj-Hyperlink]
FROM 
    t_object obj 
INNER JOIN 
    t_objectproperties objp ON (obj.object_id = objp.object_id)
WHERE 
    obj.object_id = #OBJECTID# 
    AND obj.Stereotype = 'Data-Stream' 
    AND objp.Property NOT IN ('isEncapsulated')
ORDER BY 
    objp.Property ASC;
```

[image]

I found that the when these  fields are longer than 249 chars I get an error message when generating the reports and the cell in the generated table is simply empty. This is also noticeable with a query:

[image]

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error Processing xml document: an invalid character was found in text context"

Is there any workaround to enable including the `<memo>` fields' data with more than 249 chars in the reports?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's an MS-Access limit of 255 chararters for text fields, and this is probably what's going on. Not sure if there is a workaround, but you could try to see what happens if you simply select the notes field without the Switch statement. (PS. proper SQL syntax would be CASE WHEN instead of the Switch function.)

Comment: in fact it seems that just doing 'objp.Notes AS Val' the output no longer gets truncated. however, I really need that logic there because there are some properties fields that are not memo fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this by joining two queries with a "Union all". The first query will handle the non-memo fields with the switch function and the second one the memo fields without the switch function.

```
    select 
     obj.object_id, 
     obj.Stereotype, 
     objp.Property as Prop, 
     objp.Notes AS Val, 
     (
      SELECT 
       tobj2.ea_guid & tobj2.Name 
      FROM 
       t_object tobj2 
      WHERE 
      tobj2.ea_guid = objp.Value
     ) AS [Obj-Hyperlink] 
  from 
     t_objectproperties objp 
     left join t_object obj on (obj.object_id = objp.object_ID) 
  where 
     obj.object_id = #OBJECTID# 
     AND obj.Stereotype = 'Data-Stream' 
     AND objp.Property NOT IN ('isEncapsulated') 
     AND objp.Value = "<memo>" 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
     obj2.object_id, 
     obj2.Stereotype, 
     objp2.Property as Prop, 
     switch(
      objp2.Value LIKE '{*}', NULL, 1 = 1, objp2.Value
     ) AS Val, 
     (
      SELECT 
        tobj2.ea_guid & tobj2.Name 
      FROM 
        t_object tobj2 
      WHERE 
        tobj2.ea_guid = objp2.Value
     ) AS [Obj-Hyperlink] 
  FROM 
     t_object obj2 
     INNER JOIN t_objectproperties objp2 ON (obj2.object_id = objp2.object_id) 
  WHERE 
     obj2.object_id = #OBJECTID# 
     AND obj2.Stereotype = 'Data-Stream' 
     AND objp2.Property NOT IN ('isEncapsulated') 
     and objp2.Value <> "<memo>" 
  order by 
     3 asc;
```

Thanks a lot @geertbellekens for your comment which was crucial to find this solution.